# How to customize screen resolution reported to a JavaScript application by a web browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, privacy, web, web-development

`window.screen.availHeight` and `window.screen.availWidth` values let web applications to know my actual screen resolution while I don't always want them to know it. Can I set my own values for these properties? I am interested in solutions for both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. It is possible in theory to overwrite the `window.screen.availHeight` and `window.screen.availWidth` properties using the `Object.defineProperty` function.

Try the following file:

**test.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.alert("Window resolution before overwrite is " + window.screen.availWidth + " x " + window.screen.availHeight);
      Object.defineProperty(window.screen, "availWidth", { get: function(){return 0; }});
      Object.defineProperty(window.screen, "availHeight", { get: function(){return 0; }});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.alert("Window resolution after overwrite is " + window.screen.availWidth + " x " + window.screen.availHeight);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, to answer your question of a generic way to make this happen on all sites, I can only provide a partial answer.

Using UserScripts (through Greasemonkey) on Firefox the following script has the desired effect (to use, install the Greasemonkey add-in then restart Firefox and drag the script onto the Firefox window).

**Hide_screen_resolution.user.js**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Hide screen resolution
// @description   This script hides access to the screen resolution through window.screen.availHeight and window.screen.availWidth values.
// @include       *
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

Object.defineProperty(window.screen, "availWidth", { get: function(){return 0; }});
Object.defineProperty(window.screen, "availHeight", { get: function(){return 0; }});
```

Now if test.html is opened again it can be seen that the screen resolution before the overwrite is already reset providing the desired results.

**Unfortunately Chrome does not support running code such as this before the document is loaded so this UserScript does not work there. I have posted this answer in the hope that someone can hint at a possible solution in Chrome.**