# How to force Firefox to fake the system's screen resolution like TOR does?

Tags: firefox, tor

When using [any service like this one](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/). You’ll notice [TOR Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) sends the current windows’ width and height as if they were the computer’s real screen resolution; TOR is basically lying here.

I wish to have the same effect on my Mozilla browser too. I tried to search in `about:config` and compare both of them for any switch, but haven’t found anything so far. There has to be a way to this because TOR and Mozilla are same thing.

A permanent option from configuration would be great, please I'm not looking for any solution that requires manual clicks before each navigation.

Comment: The first link appears broken ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: It works fine from my side. Basically it's a webpage that shows something like: `YOU ARE USING: 1280 x 1024`. If it's still not showing then please google: `what is my screen resolution` for an other alternative, any would do..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/712461/how-to-customize-screen-resolution-reported-to-a-javascript-application-by-a-web

Answer (score 1):

Tor's change in screen resolution change is in libxul.so which means it is in the source code. So you would have to create a custom firefox build to accomplish that.

There is a workaround but it requires other programs.
First, run a vnc/rdp server and connect to it with a vnc/rdp client.
Then, configure the resolution (of either the client or the server),
and run Firefox inside of it.

Comment: a more detailed answer with step by step instructions & links to relevant 'other programs' & source of information will improve the quality of your answer & will be more useful to @Heidi. click on 'edit' to do so.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to fake the screen resolution directly. For example, under Linux, xrandr can split a physical display into multiple virtual monitors. Not all window mangers under Linux respect xrandr's monitor setting though.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/150066/split-monitor-in-two